# Умножение чисел с помощью рекурсии

Tags: java, рекурсия

Стараюсь понять как работает рекурсия. Вот пример как перемножить два числа с помощью цикла:

```
public int mult(int a, int b){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<b;i++){
        sum+=a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Пожалуйста подскажите, как переделать этот цикл с помощью рекурсии ? (используя только сложение)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение в лоб достаточно тривиальное, но даже здесь надо учитывать наличие граблей:

```
private int mult_step(int summand, int steps_count){
    if (steps_count > 0)
        return summand + mult(summand, steps_count - 1);
    else
        return 0;
}

public int mult(int a, int b){
    int summand, steps_count;
    Boolean negate;
    if(a > b){
        summand = a;
        steps_count = Math.abs(b);
        negate = (b < 0);
    } else{
        summand = b;
        steps_count = Math.abs(a);
        negate = (a < 0);
    }

    int sum = mult_step(summand, steps_count);
    return negate ? -sum : sum;
}
```

То есть сначала мы спускаемся вглубь по цепочке из *b* элементов, после чего начинаем подниматься обратно, накапливая сумму.

Поясню, о каких граблях шла речь:

1. Множители могут быть отрицательными. Если это не учесть, то будет бесконечная рекурсия.
2. При больших *b* цепочка получится длиннее, чем может вместить в себя стек. Поэтому в качестве длины цепочки надо брать наименьший из множителей.

Answer (score 1):

Можно по аналогии с [алгоритмом быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C):

```
public static int mul(int a, int b){
    if (b < 0) return -mul(a, -b); // обработка отрицательных значений
    if (b == 1) return a;          // тривиальные условия выхода 

    if ((b & 1) == 1)  return a + mul(a, b-1); // обработка нечётных
    return mul(a, b >> 1) << 1;                // логарифмический спуск на чётных
}
```

Рабочее демо на js:

```js
function mul(a, b) {
  if (b < 0) return -mul(a, -b);
  if (b == 1) return a;
  if ((b&1) == 1)  return a + mul(a, b-1);
  return mul(a, b >> 1) << 1;
  // за счёт деления на 2 мы получаем всего logN итераций
}

[
  [2, 7],
  [3, 8],
  [-13, -17],
].forEach(([a, b]) => console.log(
  a, b, 
  mul(a, b), 
  mul(a, b) === a*b
));
```

Comment: @And, прокомментируйте пожалуйста

Answer (score -2):

Можно еще так:

```
int mult(int min, int max) {
    if (min == max) {
        return max;
    }
    return mult(++min, max);
}
```

Но все зависит от того, что за операции нужно делать.

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь, что это работает. Вы делаете max-min итераций, но возвращаете всё равно неизменённый max..

Comment: @vp_arth, так попробуйте, я между прочим пробовал и все работает, как нужно.

Comment: [Плохо пробовали](http://rextester.com/POKV1062)

Comment: Мало того, что ответ неверный, так вообще не ясно, зачем тут `++min`, если параметры в java не по ссылке передаются.

Comment: @vp_arth, господи, вы глаза откройте... Срабатывает выражение `min==max` когда `min` достигает `max`, и возвращает `max`, что же тут не правильно о сударь? Это же пример, причем правильный и рабочий, вопрос был про рекурсию и как работает, а какие условия будут это не волнует..

Comment: Но чем это отличается от `int mult(int min, int max) { return max; }` ? Или даже `int mult(int min, int max) { return min<=max?max:mult(min, max); }` включая переполнение буфера. Где тут умножение-то?